# javascript, posição do mouse em um elemento

Tags: javascript, mouse

Para saber a posição do mouse em um elemento uso `elm.onmouseover(mouse)`, porém não é possível usar isso se ele já estiver em cima desse elemento, e `elm.onmousemove(mouse)`, teria que necessariamente mover o mouse, como obter a posição do mouse em relação a um elemento quando ele já está em cima dele sem usar `elm.onmousemove()`?

Comment: Na sua interação, o mouse se mexe alguma vez e para? Ou é preciso pegar as coordenadas mesmo que o mouse não tenha se mexido em momento algum?

Comment: não, ele não necessariamente se movimenta... quando se movimenta é tranquilo, o evento "onmousemove" resolve o problema... Imagino que o que você vai sugerir é ficar regravando uma variável que tenha um valor inicial indicando que o mouse não está em cima do elemento e volte para esse valor quando o evento "onmouseleave" ocorrer. É que passei a fazer logo depois de postar essa pergunta. Só que isso não funciona quando a página carrega com o mouse parado em cima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o mouse pode não ter se movido, você pode usar o evento [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) para pegar as coordenadas iniciais, depois continue atualizando as coordenadas com `onmousemove` como você já está fazendo.

```
var x = null;
var y = null;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseUpdate, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseUpdate, false);

function onMouseUpdate(e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
}
```

Esse evento dispara no page load, então mesmo que o mouse não se mova, as coordenadas já estão disponíveis nas variáveis x e y.

[Exemplo tirado dessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601097/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-without-events-without-moving-the-mouse)